# 'Add another' fieldset on a multi-step webform

Tags: webforms

I have a multi-step webform using ajax (I'm using webform steps and webform ajax modules). 
The webform contains several pages (i.e education, career and experience).
In education page i have the following fields: degree and major which are placed inside a fieldset.

I tried using the webform add more module but it wasn't working (not displaying) although i followed up several recommendations and i know how it works. You need to specify the number of fieldsets, it doesn't create them dynamically.

Is there any other way for me to use the 'add another degree and major' feature?

I am using Drupal 7 and the Webform module 7.x-4.19.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) in the form. It got the feature of adding multiple fieldset on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I"m assuming I need to use entity forms instead of webforms if i'm to use field collection, is that correct?